# Syntax highlighting for git syntax in gedit

Tags: configuration, git, gedit

Is there a way to automatically get syntax highlighting for git syntax in gedit?

I set gedit as my default git editor with `git config --global core.editor "gedit -s"`. Now when I type `git commit`, gedit pops up so I can type a commit message. It also shows a diff of the commit below in the git diff syntax: Changed lines are preceeded with `-` or `+`, git messages are preceded with `@`, etc. I would like these lines to be highlighted with red, green and other colors as in command line git diff tools.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be one. However, I guess we can make one and add it to the repository, similar to [this Merge Request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtksourceview/-/merge_requests/154). According to [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtksourceview/-/issues/150), they only accept Merge Requests, not any feature request. (In other words, if you want it, make it yourself.)